# In webpack, is there a way to transpile two different react codes at the same time

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm making a react project. I have two separate pages that have their own separate react code. I've managed to compile them separately on webpack by just changing the input and output name, but I was wondering if I could have more than one entry and output on webpack

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './B/js/class_slider.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/B/static/js/'),
    filename: 'class_slider_compiled.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        // Test for js or jsx files
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          // Convert ES6 syntax to ES5 for browser compatibility
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

then in my terminal I run

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

I want to be able to transpile multiple things at once because it is very annoying to switch the entry input and output every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export an array of configs from webpack.config.js:

```
const config1 = {
  entry: './entry-one.js',
  output: './output-one.js',
  ...etc
}

const config2 = {
  entry: './entry-two.js',
  output: './output-two.js',
  ...etc
}

module.exports = [config1, config2];
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had enough reputation to upvote